# Scrolling not working on Samsung Internet

Tags: javascript, android

I'm creating a chat app, and I tried to implement autoscroll feature for it.
But it's not working on Samsung Internet(It's worked on Firefox Dev Edition(normal mode and interactive design mode) and Chrome Mobile), especially when I used the submit button on the keyboard. Here's the screenshots:
[Firefox Dev Edition Interactive Design Mode Screenshot(gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW9PS.gif)
[Samsung Internet Screenshot(gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxsOT.gif)

And here's the code:

```
let chatview = document.querySelector('#chatview')
if (chatview.scrollTop >= chatview.scrollHeight - chatview.clientHeight)
  setTimeout(() => chatview.scrollTo(0, chatview.scrollHeight), 50)
```

Oh, and the reason why I added 50ms delay is to wait for element addition(powered by Vue's v-for).

Comment: Can you see any error/warning in console logs or logcat? Is your text is added on screen?

Comment: @VicJordan Text was added. It's appeared when I scrolled #chatview. I tried to connect debugger to Samsung Internet but failed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for those who are still looking for an answer: I had the same problem with Samsung Internet version 7.4.00.70. I've tried several scroll-methods (see below). Seems to be an implementation issue.

Functions i've tested:

```
// Throws an error saying the method is not defined
window.scrollTo(ScrollToOptions)
// Throws an error saying the method is not defined
window.scroll(ScrollToOptions)
// Throws no error (!) but doesn't work either
window.scroll(x, y)
```

Links: [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll), [window.scroll(ScrollToOptions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll), [window.scroll(x, y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)

Since version 7.4 reached stable state in August 2018, i would have expected it to work.

**EDIT: Working solution**

I've found a solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024949/scrolling-scrollbar-locks-after-scrolltop-animation) using jQuery.[animate(( properties [, duration][, easing][, complete]))](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$(element).animate(
   { scrollTop: scrolling },                 // Object of CSS properties
   250,                                      // Duration
   'easeOutQuad',                            // jQuery's Easing
   () => { $(element).stop(true, true); }    // Callback function
);
```

Here `element` is the HTML elemente the animation is to be applied on. For detailed explanation of `animate()` please follow the link. The specified callback function is executed when the animation has been completed. Calling `$(element).stop(true, true)` ([see](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)) prevents the scrollbar of being locked. This happened in Chrome when the window was resized. In my case the resize event triggered execution of `animate()` and i wasn't able to scroll neither by mouse wheel nor by dragging the scrollbar.

This workaround is working on latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, Firefox mobile, Chrome mobile, Samsung Internet Browser and Opera mobile.

I wasn't able to test it on safari. You need at least jQuery 1.8.